# Is there a Python expression for Does Not Contain that I can use in a Update Cursor?

Tags: arcpy, cursor

Is there a Python expression for Does Not Contain that I can use in a Update Cursor? I am looking for the '@' symbol in a column within a table (not a FC) and want to delete all entries without one, is there a way accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the WHERE clause in your Update Cursor use

> myField NOT LIKE '%@%'

The '%' sign is a wildcard character representing any number of characters, including 0 characters.

The call would look something like this.

```
cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(contacts, #your table
                               ['*'],    #your fields
                               "Contact_Email NOT LIKE '%@%'") #your where clause
for row in cursor:
    cursor.deleteRow()
del cursor
```

Comment: Would it look like the following?

Comment: with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(contacts, "Contact_Email") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row NOT LIKE '%@%':
            cursor.deleteRow()

Comment: @winscott68 what happened when you tested that?

Comment: @winscott68 I added the call to UpdateCursor to my answer.

Comment: It did not work I got a syntax error for the following line ;  for row in cursor:

Comment: cursor=arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(contacts,['Contact_Email'],"Contact_Email NOT LIKE '%@%"
    for row in cursor:
        if row NOT LIKE '%@%': 
            cursor.deleteRow()

Comment: @winscott68 The cursor itself is already limiting what is returned based on the where clause. There is no need to compare the specific row to the pattern string again.

Comment: Make sure your fields are spelled correctly and refer to the real field name (not the alias) in your table. Also it looks like you are missing a single quote after the second percentage sign. Make sure the %@% is enclosed in single quotation marks. If that doesn't work it would be helpful if you posted a screenshot of your table.